# amCharts angular directive cannot change ChartScrollbar draghandles

Tags: amcharts

I cannot seem to get amCharts to respect the `dragIcon` property on the `ChartScrollbar`. I have [a plunk here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7toIpZAIRShA2DCOWWdq?p=preview) that demonstrates the problem.

I suspect this is a problem with the [GrantMStevens amChartsDirective](https://github.com/GrantMStevens/amCharts-Angular) because of the previous problem I had with it not passing properties correctly and the fact that [it works in this demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwYWGy#anon-login).  The previous was debugged by [xorspark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6106614/xorspark), and I was able to replicate his debugging, but this is not broken in the same way. Unfortunately, I am not yet good enough at debugging JavaScript to track this one down.

**Anyone have any ideas?**

```
  'use strict';
    angular.module('App')
    .controller('MyChartController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = {};

        $scope.amChartOptions = {
        type: "serial",
        creditsPosition: "upper-left",

        categoryField: "IncidentId",
        rotate: true,
        theme: "light",
        categoryAxis: {
            parseDates: false,
            gridAlpha: 0.3,
            gridColor: "#d3d3d3"
        },
        trendLines: [],
        pathToImages: "http://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
        chartScrollbar: {
            oppositeAxis: true,
            autoGridCount: true,
            graph: "AmGraph-1",
            scrollbarHeight: 65,
            dragIcon: "dragIconRoundSmall",
            dragIconHeight: 65,
            backgroundColor: "#000",
            //color: "#000",
            backgroundAlpha: .5,
            selectedBackgroundColor: "#337ab7",
            svgIcons: true
        },
        graphs: [{
            fillColorsField: "lineColor",
            lineColorField: "lineColor",
            balloonText: "[[title]] for [[category]]: [[value]]",
            fillAlphas: 1,
            id: "AmGraph-1",
            title: "Escalation Age",
            type: "column",
            valueField: "Age"
        }],
        guides: [],
        valueAxes: [{
            baseValue: 0,
            id: "ValueAxis-1",
            labelFrequency: 1,
            dateFormats: [],
            title: "Days Active",
            autoGridCount: true,
            gridAlpha: 0.3,
            gridColor: "#d3d3d3",
        }],
        allLabels: [],
        balloon: {},
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        titles: [{
            id: "Title-1",
            size: 15,
            text: ""
        }],
        data: [
            {
            "lineColor": "#ff0000",
            "IncidentId": 93528214,
            "Age": 19
        },{
            "lineColor": "#ff0000",
            "IncidentId": 93434314,
            "Age": 16
        },{
            "lineColor": "#ff0000",
            "IncidentId": 93524544,
            "Age": 12
        },{
            "lineColor": "#ff0000",
            "IncidentId": 93525454,
            "Age": 10
        },{
            "lineColor": "#ff0000",
            "IncidentId": 96578214,
            "Age": 4
        },{
            "lineColor": "#ff0000",
            "IncidentId": 93334519,
            "Age": 2
        }]
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old 3.13.0 version of AmCharts on cdnjs doesn't support changing the `dragIcon`. You need to use a more recent version. The latest version of the AmCharts library can be found on AmCharts' own CDN:

```
  <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
  <script src="https://https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/chalk.js"></script>
  <script src="https://https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/black.js"></script>
  <script src="https://https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/dark.js"></script>
```

Updated plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/mw4f2FWiTsFkOdjd3tkE?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. I am sad and embarrassed :(

Comment: For my own edification, how did you know that was the problem? I also assume this is why I should be pulling a specific version into my repo and then swapping it for the CDN when I publish a stable version, yes?

Comment: Well, I *am* part of the AmCharts support staff, so I can ask the team directly. :) You're more than welcome to pull whichever version you need if you need to freeze your application on a specific version for your own maintenence purposes, however you inherit any unfixed bugs or features that aren't in that version. If you like to live on the bleeding edge, you can link to our CDN. For some reason, Grant's directive still references very old versions of our charts in his demos and his bower file, so that unfortunately leads to issues like this. :(